# Specify col_types in readODS::read_ods

Tags: r, double, ods

I want to read in R a range from an ods file, of which first column must be character, and the other 40 columns must be doubles. How do I specify the col_types? `col_types = paste0("c", paste(rep("d", times = 40), collapse = ""))` does not work, I get the error `Unknown col_types. Can either be a class col_spec, NULL or NA`. I cannot find any examples. Anyone a hint for a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`col_types` should be of class `col_spec`. It means, that you can define column type with `readr::cols()`.

Let's say you have this table in `table.ods`:

```
           A       B            C
1 characters numbers againnumbers
2          a       1            5
3          a       2            6
4          a       3            7
5          a       4            8
```

Then you can specify the columns with [`readr::cols()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/cols.html): the first column (named `characters` here) as characters by [`readr::col_character()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_atomic.html) and others by default as numbers with [`readr::col_double()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/parse_atomic.html):

```
library(readODS)
library(readr)

df <- read_ods("table.ods",
               col_types = cols(
                   characters = col_character(),
                   .default = col_double())
)

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#> $ characters  : chr  "0" "1" "2" "3"
#> $ numbers     : num  1 2 3 4
#> $ againnumbers: num  5 6 7 8
```

(If you want to use simple method with e.g. `"cdd"`, you need to convert that string to `col_spec` with [`readr::as.col_spec()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/as.col_spec.html), however it's not named and doesn't seem to work correctly with `read_ods()`.)

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks! The simple "cdd" did not work though. It did not give errors, but did not make the last column into a double. But the more elegant way with .default did work. No errors and the desired format.

Comment: @MartineJ Great, thanks for your feedback, it's great it works for you! I have tried that again and it really seems that simple converting "cdd" and using with read_ods() does not work correctly... I have removed that from the answer as it could confuse someone, thanks!